# Covariance matrix in PCA approach

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, covariance, principal-component-analysis

While reading the brief discussion on the PCA approach in the book Deep Learning (Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville), I could not understand the passage shown in the figure.
Specifically when the authors go to compute the covariance matrix of the encoded input $\vec{z}$.
Since $\vec{z}$ has been defined to be $W^T\vec{x}$, I don't understand how $Z^TZ$ can be $W^TX^TXW$. According to my reasoning it should instead be: $X^TWW^TX$. Can anyone tell me where am I wrong?

[image]

The discussion about that is given on page 146 (Part I - section 5) of the book (https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html).

Comment: I happen to be reading this book as well, but I haven't reached this chapter yet. Looking it over briefly, it appears that $x$ and $X$ are not the same thing. See for example equation 5.85: $\displaystyle \operatorname{Var}[x] = \frac{1}{m-1}X^T X$.

Comment: $X$ is an $m \times n$ "design matrix" according to the paragraph above equation 5.85. This is defined on page 103 as "a matrix containing a different example in each row." I'm guessing $x$ is a $n \times 1$ random column vector and $X$ is a matrix containing $m$ sample instances of $x$ but arranged in rows instead of columns. This transposition from columns to rows could explain the apparent discrepancy you observed. If $z = W^T x$ is the column vector notation, then in row form it would be $z^T = x^T W$. Then if you stack $m$ instances of these rows to form $Z$ and $X$, it would be $Z = XW$.

Comment: ...which is consistent with equations 5.92 and 5.93 depicted in your question.

Comment: @Bungo perfect!